# Why am I getting TypeError on length property

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

For this code:

```
var getSuggestions = function(query) {
searchService.getSuggestions(query).then(function(es_return){
  var suggestions = es_return.suggest.phraseSuggestion;
  var results = es_return.hits.hits;

  if (suggestions.length > 0) {
    $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = suggestions;
  }
  else {
    $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = [];
  }

  if (results.length > 0) {
    $scope.autocomplete.results = results;
  }
  else {
    $scope.autocomplete.results = [];
  }

  if (suggestions.length > 0 || results.length > 0) {
    $scope.showAutocomplete = true;
  }
  else {
    $scope.showAutocomplete = false; 
  }
});
```

};

Specifically on the first if statement and I don't see why? Need some fresh eyes to show me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that suggestions it's a String?

Comment: @Error404 its an array of strings

Comment: `es_return.suggest.phraseSuggestion === undefined` that's what your TypeError is saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I drilled down on this more, I noticed that I had an issue with the ES query that I was using for the ac code. It was actually just a typo. Where I had `phrasesuggestion` in the js, I had `phrase_suggestion` in the json query for ES, once I fixed that - it worked! Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need some better null handling. With  `Suggestion.length > 0` null cannot be evaluated with `>`, right?  So probably use boolean instead (or both).

```
if (Suggestion.length){
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the code from the developer console.

Probably you should `es_return.hits.hits` remake to `es_return.hits`.

In your case `es_return.hits.hits` or `suggestions` are not an array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `es_return.suggest.phraseSuggestion` is `undefined`.You can try like this:

```
if(suggestions != undefined)
{
if (suggestions.length > 0) {
    $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = suggestions;
  }
  else {
    $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = [];
  }
}
```